# How to use key prop in components in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two components i.e.**CollapsableCard** and **InnerParentCard**.

InnerParentCard is the child of CollapsableCard and CollapsableCard is the child of the main screen.

Under the main screen, I have a return component for CollapsableCard.

```
 <SalaryCardFlatList
          data={allCardTitle}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
<CollapsibleCard
         
         data={item.innerData}
         formTitle={item["@TEUR"]}
         tashlumBody={tashlumBody}
         isTabularFormat={item.isTabularFormat}
         isTitleText={item.isTitleText}
       />
}
```

below is the array rendering for CollapsableCard.

```
props.data.forEach((obj, objIndex) => {
      innerArray = allInnerContent.map((keyName, index) => {
        if (props.isTabularFormat) {
          if (index === hebrewMonthArray.length - 1) {
            return (
              <DataTable.Cell style={styles.dataTableCell}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 9 }}> {obj["@VALUE_SUM"]}</Text>
              </DataTable.Cell>
            );
          } else {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(`@VALUE${index + 1}`)) {
              return (
                <DataTable.Cell style={styles.dataTableCell}>
                  <Entypo name="check" size={20} color="#1F75FE" />
                </DataTable.Cell>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <DataTable.Cell style={styles.dataTableCell}></DataTable.Cell>
              );
            }
          }
        }
        //NOTE:taken styleValue for aligning each index value of innerContain
        const styleVar = index === 0 ? styles.value : styles.innerValue;
        const styleValue =
          index === 0
            ? styles.firstIndexValue
            : index === 1
            ? styles.secondIndexvalue
            : index === 2
            ? styles.thirdIndexValue
            : styles.innerValue;
        if (!props.isTitleText) {
          return <Text style={styleVar}>{obj[keyName]}</Text>;
        } else return <Text style={styleValue}>{obj[keyName]}</Text>;
      });
```

Under CollapsableCard component, I have InnerParentCard.

```
 <InnerParentCard
              
                tashlumList={props.tashlumList[`${objIndex + 1}`]}
                allTashlumValue={obj}
                formBodyValue={props.formBody}
                updateValue={updateValue}
                isHelpMessage={helpMessage}
                isSubTitleText={subTitleText}
                isKav1Present={props.isKav1Present}
                isTotalAmount={totalAmount}
                allTashlumSection={props.allTashlumArray[`${objIndex}`]}
                allChildSection={props.allTashlumChildSection[`${objIndex}`]}
                isHefAmount={hefAmount}
                isAhuzAmount={ahuzAmount}
                isFromDate={fromDate}
                isToDate={toDate}
              ></InnerParentCard>
```

below is the rendering for InnerParentCard.

```
 allInnerContent.forEach((tashlum, index) => {
    const styleVar =
      index === 0
        ? styles.value
        : index === 1
        ? styles.innerValue
        : styles.titleValue;
    const styleValue =
      index === 0 ? styles.firstIndexvalue : styles.LastIndexValue;
    {
      !props.isKav1Present
        ? allTashlum.push(
            <TashlumView>
              <Text style={styleVar}>{props.allTashlumValue[tashlum]}</Text>
            </TashlumView>
          )
        : allTashlum.push(
            <TashlumView>
              <Text style={styleValue}>{props.allTashlumValue[tashlum]}</Text>
            </TashlumView>
          );
    }
  });
```

for these two components, it is showing warnings for both child components.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `CollapsibleCard`.
```

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `InnerParentCard`.
```

How to pass key prop to  CollapsableCard and InnerParentCard components?

Comment: If `CollapsibleCard` is mapping and rendering an array and you've an issue with React keys, please include its implementation in your question. If `InnerParentCard ` is mapping and rendering an array and you've an issue with React keys, please include its implementation in your question.

Comment: now you can check the question..@DrewReese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each array that either component is rendering they still need to include a unique React key prop for each mapped element being rendered.

CollapsableCard

```
props.data.forEach((obj, objIndex) => {
  innerArray = allInnerContent.map((keyName, index) => {
    if (props.isTabularFormat) {
      if (index === hebrewMonthArray.length - 1) {
        return (
          <DataTable.Cell
            key={/* some unique key value here */}
            style={styles.dataTableCell}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 9 }}> {obj["@VALUE_SUM"]}</Text>
          </DataTable.Cell>
        );
      } else {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(`@VALUE${index + 1}`)) {
          return (
            <DataTable.Cell
              key={/* some unique key value here */}
              style={styles.dataTableCell}
            >
              <Entypo name="check" size={20} color="#1F75FE" />
            </DataTable.Cell>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <DataTable.Cell
              key={/* some unique key value here */}
              style={styles.dataTableCell}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    }
    //NOTE:taken styleValue for aligning each index value of innerContain
    const styleVar = index === 0 ? styles.value : styles.innerValue;
    const styleValue =
      index === 0
        ? styles.firstIndexValue
        : index === 1
        ? styles.secondIndexvalue
        : index === 2
        ? styles.thirdIndexValue
        : styles.innerValue;

    return (
      <Text
        key={/* some unique key value here */}
        style={!props.isTitleText ? styleVar : styleValue}
      >
        {obj[keyName]}
      </Text>
    );
  });
```

InnerParentCard

```
allInnerContent.forEach((tashlum, index) => {
  ...

  allTashlum.push(
    <TashlumView key={/* some unique key value here */}>
      <Text style={!props.isKav1Present ? styleVar : styleValue}>
        {props.allTashlumValue[tashlum]}
      </Text>
    </TashlumView>
  );
  ...
});
```

The `key={/* some unique key value here */}` can, and should, be any unique key value that is intrinsic to the mapped element, i.e. an `id` or any unique property, or combination of properties, so long as it is unique among the immediate siblings. Avoid random keys and the index.